# Typescript: type check that record can be constructed out of a list of pieces of record

Tags: typescript

I want something like this function:

```js
<RecordType>(list: Partial<RecordType>[]) => RecordType
```

How can I type check that all elements in the list will correspond to one and only one piece of the record?

Example:

```js
type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
};

fromPieces<Person>([
 { name: "oscar" },
 { id: "arst" },
 { lastname: "mendez" }
]) => ({
  name: "oscar",
  id: "arst",
  lastname: "mendez"
});
```

Comment: I guess that is not possible. The types are only available during compile time. As you put Partial<Type>s into the list you can not guarantee that you put every required part of your type into the array to build a "whole" type. The only possible thing I can imagine would be something like `<T> (...parts: Partial<T>) => Partial<T>` .But I am interested in other users' option

Comment: Maybe I can do it at runtime, but part of my problem is that I don't even know how to start building it so that I don't have to use any at the end.

Comment: This is possible but a lot of hoops to make the type system jump through, with consequent caveats and edge cases. As such, you need to specify the exact behavior you want with more examples. Like, [this](//tsplay.dev/mpvXBw) is a possible approach, but without good tests it's hard to know if it will meet your needs.  Also, it's a weird way of building up an object; if you do care about such one-property objects, maybe you want to use a builder pattern instead like [this](//tsplay.dev/m3aQ1w), which is easier for the compiler to reason about. Do you want me to write any of this up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained in my comment I think that this is not possible as you can not statically typecheck that you put every "Partial" of the "Type" into the function to guarantee that you can build a whole "Type" of it.

But you can write a generic function aggregating the parts to a more complete Partial.

I don't know it this is the direction you want to go but this is a simple example:

```
const builder = <T> (...parts: Partial<T>[]):Partial<T> =>
  parts.reduce((acc, part) => ({...acc, ...part}), {})

builder<{x: number, y: number}>({x: 5}, {y: 3}) // this works

builder<{x: number, y: number}>({x: 5}, {z: 3}) // this gives an error
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with recursive types but its order dependen.
You need to cast Person to Unions, so with EntriesOf I convert `Person` to: `{ id: string } | { name: string } | { lastname: string }`

And then you can cast the union to an array with a requirement for each type.
So `UnionToTuple` converts it to `[{ id: string }, { name: string }, { lastname: string }]`

With that, you can ensure that every property is present on the input, but it also order dependent(this can be fixed tho).

```
type EntriesOf<Type> = { [Key in keyof Type]: Pick<Type, Key> }[keyof Type];

type UnionToTuple<T> = (
    (
        (
            T extends any
                ? (t: T) => T
                : never
        ) extends infer U
            ? (U extends any
                ? (u: U) => any
                : never
            ) extends (v: infer V) => any
                ? V
                : never
            : never
    ) extends (_: any) => infer W
        ? [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, W>>, W]
        : []
);


type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
};


function fromPieces<T>(arg: UnionToTuple<EntriesOf<T>>): T {
    return {} as T;
}

// this works 
const test = fromPieces<Person>([
  { id: "" },
  { name: "" },
  { lastname: "test" } 
])

// this wont work
const test1 = fromPieces<Person>([
  { name: "" },
  { id: "" },
  { lastname: "test" } 
])
```

[See it in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATgSwgZwPIDMA8AVcCAPigF4oBvKAbQGkIQpk4oBrBgeyygMgF0AXFAAKyAMat8hADRR6IEgF9q7EFx6E+AbgBQO0JCgBVOMg5w8HPAFcwAGwj4S5ABQ6oHqG88+v73wF4UBAAHsAQcAAmaFAAhnAg-gHJUAD8XsBCeACUZCR4SSm+QnAQAG4QiIU+uaHhUTHMWJXG1cnpLkbBYRHRcQltRWle1kJGuaQk8YlDASXllYO+tT0NXmVCTS0AahNTA7O+6dtLKfMVVYfnizXd9X0uAPpC03tMcM2IUADqS+nUADogSYzBYrLYHDgYCExHZrJFHHhZN8iERkXwlkJqBjsro9AZoMJKmhzGRKP5kJEhGgkMwAOa6DxwWIAWwg1NpcAZ-jssRpzLZHJQXN0ijxOiw1jgYmAoKgWEQHBZoggYnQThcsUQdLGpnMlhs9kc8Fp6GwTiI2Sy5J8iAgwGsiBYFEUcRieFFegA9F6oMAABbIGIAdw4iFYMR0YnMNL96GAZIVSpVarQOCJiBJcCILmo-iolKEACIi1BFNJ81ABeyoCWyxWPFRefzWTWi+EaaXXTo+Nlvb6A0GoKGEMOw6wozGEx3gABGROK5WoVPp4nmHN5xtV1vFrsNyhMKm1veV5vAavFmddqA97JAA)

Credits to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-707364842 for the `UnionToTuple` type.